# No mapping found for field in order to sort on in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, mapping, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch throws a `SearchParseException` while parsing query if there are some documents found not containing field used in sort criteria.

> SearchParseException: Parse Failure [No mapping found for [price] in order to sort on]

How can I successfully search these documents, even if some are missing the `price` field?

Comment: Your question/answer solved my problem - thank you. I edited to generalize it somewhat, feel free to rollback if that doesn't suit you.

Comment: Reference for handling this issue [Elasticsearch Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

After digging more, I found the solution as given below. `ignore_unmapped` should be explicitly set to `true` in the sort clause.

```
"sort" : [
       { "rating": {"order" : "desc" , "ignore_unmapped" : true} },
       { "price": {"order" : "asc" , "missing" : "_last" , "ignore_unmapped" : true} }
]
```

For further information have a look at the Elasticsearch references for:

- [missing values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_missing_values)
- [ignoring unmapped fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I don't understand how this works... The attributes missing and ignore_unmapped should work together right ? If for example I set missing to "_last" and ignore_unmapped to "false", I still have the problem but I want the documents to be in the results in all cases even if they don't have the attribute.

Comment: I have this problem and "ignore_unmapped" don't work if your _type is empty (i.e. without any document indexed).

Comment: Looks like the new strategy is to use [unmapped_type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields)

Comment: My queries always worked until today without updating any libraries etc. but today I started getting this same error. I now added `"ignore_unmapped" : true` and it started to work again but strange thing is, what has happened behind the scene! Who knows! Anyway, it works now. +1

Comment: Can someone clarify the difference between "missing" and "unmapped"? For a certain field, if some documents have it while others don't, is such field treated as "missing" or "unmapped"? Does "missing" mean the field is in the document but the corresponding value is null?

Comment: For making the NEST 6.x  change, please follow this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sort-usage.html

Answer (score 61):

> For those looking for an example of both `ignore_unmapped` and
>   `unmapped_type` please see [my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103603/elasticsearch-queries-on-empty-index/31134042#31134042).

Note that "ignore_unmapped" is now deprecated in favor of "unmapped_type". This was done as part of [#7039](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7039)

[From documentation:](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_ignoring_unmapped_fields) Before 1.4.0 there was the ignore_unmapped boolean parameter, which was not enough information to decide on the sort values to emit, and didn’t work for cross-index search. It is still supported but users are encouraged to migrate to the new unmapped_type instead.

By default, the search request will fail if there is no mapping associated with a field. The unmapped_type option allows to ignore fields that have no mapping and not sort by them. The value of this parameter is used to determine what sort values to emit. Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "price" : {"unmapped_type" : "long"} },
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

If any of the indices that are queried doesn’t have a mapping for price then Elasticsearch will handle it as if there was a mapping of type long, with all documents in this index having no value for this field.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using es 6.7

try this one

```
sort : ["title.keyword:desc"]
```

Comment: It helped me - elastic 7.3

Answer (score 4):

Apparently ElasticSearch won't sort on null values. I was assuming it would treat null as being at the start or end (as with SQL ordering) but I believe it also triggers this error.

So if you see this error, you may need to ensure the sort attribute has a default value when it's sent to ElasticSearch.

I had this error with Rails+ElasticSearch+Tire because the sort column didn't have a default value, so was being sent to ES as null.

[This issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/896) indicates null values are handling, but it wasn't my experience. It's something worth trying anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to help in the case that the original answer doesn't work for you.
For **ES 6.x** try the code below, ignore_unmapped is deprecated.

```
"sort" : [
       { "rating": {"order" : "desc" , "unmapped_type" : "long"} },
       { "price": {"order" : "asc" , "missing" : "_last" , "unmapped_type" : "long"} }
]
```

More about sorting you can find on:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem (sorta; would get some errors, but some results), but in my case my search was being issued at the root (no index specified), and the errors I was getting were because the search/order was also looking to a Kibana index.

Stupid error, but maybe this'll help someone else who ends up here.

Comment: i have the same issue .. but when i specify ignore unmapped i dont get any sorting at all when searching the root... this limits the ability to search for me if i have to define the index ... i would simply want  all matching results to be sorted by a field if it exists, and fill use a default for those that dont..

EDIT:

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch 6.4

simply specify the index and that's it in Kibana

BEFORE

```js
GET /_search
{
 
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "document_id"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "document_id": { "order": "asc"  },
      "created_at":  { "order": "desc" }
    }
  ]
}
```

AFTER

```js
GET /document-index/contact/_search  (here)
{

  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "document_id"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "document_id": { "order": "asc"  },
      "created_at":  { "order": "desc" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use script which gives you some flexibility:

```
"sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "return !doc['price'].empty ? doc['price'].value : 0"
        },
        "order" : "desc"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use below code, where **added_on** is date, what happens !! [attribute text is analyzed, meaning it is broken up into distinct words when stored, and allows for free-text searches on one or more words in the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869795/difference-between-a-field-and-the-field-keyword)

so there is "text" and "keyword" associated with fields, so if we need to use aggregation in the query, we need the field value in general the keyword.

```
BEFORE

"_source":{....}
"query" : {...}
"sort": [
{
  "added_on": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
]

AFTER
"_source":{....}
"query" : {...}
"sort": [
{
  "added_on.keyword": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
}
]
```